# DAX calculating the average weirdly

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, measure

Im trying to calculate the avg of some IDs in a table that look like this. The letters are sub categories of each number (4 unique values):

| ID | Time | AVG time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 104 | 104 |
| ...a | 104 | 104 |
| ...b | 104 | 104 |
| 2 | 86 | 86 |
| ...a | 104 | 86 |
| 3 | 151 | 151 |
| ...c | 151 | 151 |
| ...d | 151 | 151 |
| total | 4 (4 distinct letters) | 110 |

However, when I do the AVG of my column, it tells me that the avg is 110 when in fact it should be
113.6 = (104 + 86 + 151)/3. I'm trying to get the average at the parent level and ignore the sublevels. At first, I thought this was a weighted average, but it just doesn't make sense to me how PBI is coming up with 110

Here is my Dax:

'''

```
    Measure = 
    var x = CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX(
      Table1,
          Table1[Time]
             )
    )

  var y = CALCULATE(
 DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[ID])
  )

  return
 DIVIDE(x, y )
```

'''
How do I make PBI measure to actually display the right amount which is 113.6?
Any help will be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, Average : is the `SUM` devided by the `DISTINCTCOUNT`, but in your measure you are deviding `Average` by `DISTINCTCOUNT`. try changing that

Comment: @Dordi Thank you for catching that. However, after changing it into a sum, it now gives me 183 which is still incorrect.

Comment: is there a way to differentiate between Leters and number in the `ID` column, if not you need to calculate it, it will help you to get to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

1º It is necessary to create a column indicating which level of context you want to evaluate.
In this solution, this column is named SUB-TOTAL.

Use 1 for the context to be evaluated and 0 for the context not to be evaluated.

2º It is necessary to create a calculated table that returns only the values from the context to be evaluated.

3º With the table created only with the values to be evaluated, create an "AVERAGE" measure from the column in the table created in step 2.

With this, you will have the correctly calculated average.

After these steps, it is necessary to identify how you want to present the average.

Will the average only be presented in the TOTAL OF THE TABLE?

If so, just create a conditional measure to show the average in the context you need. In this case, I only considered it in the TOTAL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbpfe.png)

```
1 - 
TABELA AVERAGE = 
  SUMMARIZE(
       Tabela,
       Tabela[Index],
       "VALOR SUB-TOTAL",
       SUMX(
        Tabela,
        CALCULATE(
          IF(
            SELECTEDVALUE(Tabela[SUB-TOTAL]) = "1",
            AVERAGE(Tabela[Hora]),
            BLANK()
          )
       )
    )
 )

2 - 
 AVERAGE = 
  AVERAGE('TABELA AVERAGE'[VALOR SUB-TOTAL])

3 - 
 AVERAGE TOTAL = 
   IF(
      ISINSCOPE(Tabela[Index]) = FALSE(),
      [AVERAGE],
      SELECTEDVALUE(Tabela[Hora])
   )
```